# How to use Flow types with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Let's say I have an `App` component whose state consists of an object whose shape is given by the following Flow type:

```
type Person = {
    fname: string,
    lname: string
};
```

To assert that the state of my component is indeed of type `Person` I create an artificial local variable inside `getInitialState` so that I can annotate the type:

```
const App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        const person : Person = {fname: 'John', lname: 'Doe'};
        return {person: person};
    }
    , render: function() {
        return (
                <PersonDetails person={this.state.person}/>
        );
    }
});
```

The above works (even though having to declare the `const person` is a minor inconvenience).
The problem arises when I wish to pass that state as the property of another component. In that case, I have found no other solution but to re-define the shape of Person using React's `PropTypes` API:

```
const PersonDetails = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        person: React.PropTypes.shape({fname: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                                       lname: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired}).isRequired
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
                <div>
                <span>{this.props.person.fname}</span>
                <span>{this.props.person.lname}</span>                
                </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This is clearly not DRY plus I am using two different methods to provide static type information (Flow and the React.PropTypes API).

Is there a way to allow the `PersonDetails` component to reuse the type declaration of `Person`?

The only way I have found is using proper classes (not React types):

```
class Person {
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    constructor(fname: string, lname: string) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
    }
};

const PersonDetails = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        person: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Person).isRequired

    },
    render: function() {
        return (
                <div>
                <span>{this.props.person.fname}</span>
                <span>{this.props.person.lname}</span>                
                </div>
        );
    }
});

const App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        const person : Person = new Person('John', 'Doe');
        return {person: person};
    }
    , render: function() {
        return (
                <PersonDetails person={this.state.person}/>
        );
    }
});

export default App;
```

… while the above succeeds in re-using the definition it is not clear to me when I ought to use Flow types versus classes to statically type-check my components. Plus, I am not sure the two methods are really equivalent (e.g. in terms of being able to express null-ability of values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your type once and export it:

```js
// types/index.js

export type Person = {|
  fname: string,
  lname: string,
|}
```

Then reuse it everywhere.

In component's `state`:

```js
// App.js

import type { Person } from './types'

type State = {|
  person: Person,
|}

class App extends Component {
  state: State = {
    person: { fname: 'John', lname: 'Doe' },
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PersonDetails person={this.state.person} />
    )
  }
}
```

In component's `props`:

```js
// components/PersonDetails.js

import type { Person } from '../types'

type Props = {|
  person: Person,
|}

// stateful syntax
class PersonDetails extends Component {
  props: Props

  render() {
    const { person } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{person.fname}</span>
        <span>{person.lname}</span>               
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// stateless syntax
const PersonDetails = ({ person }: Props) => (
  <div>
    <span>{person.fname}</span>
    <span>{person.lname}</span>               
  </div>
)
```

Comment: It appears that this is only possible if you are employing the syntax for React stateless functional components. How would you do this with `React.createClass` ?

Comment: what's the purpose of using the syntax `{| ..|}` ? Is it more idiomatic for some reason?

Comment: **First question:** You are probably misunderstanding something because all the components here are stateful. You don't need `createClass` to make a stateful component, and the ES6 syntax with `class` is now highly encouraged by the React team. As you are using ES6, I suggest you to replace your `createClass` with `class`. [According to the Flow doc](https://flowtype.org/docs/react.html#the-reactcreateclass-factory), you can't use custom Flow types with `createClass`.

Comment: **Second question:** It's the [Exact Object Type](https://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html#exact-object-types) syntax. Most people use this syntax everywhere to avoid errors.